# Why is Rails exporting all rows instead of only filtered results?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm running a Rails 4 application and am using the [Ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack) gem to filter results for employees. I've seen multiple examples of how to limit columns on the exported CSV file, but not on limiting rows. To my understanding, the following code should call the `.to_csv` method on the filtered employees, but currently all rows are being downloaded. Do I need to pass an array of the IDs of the filtered results to the `.to_csv` method?

View:

```
<h3>Download</h3>
<%= link_to "CSV", employees_path(format: "csv") %>
```

Controller:

```
def index
  @q = Employee.ransack(params[:q])
  @q.build_condition
  @employees = @q.result(distinct: true)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.csv { render text: @employees.to_csv }
  end
end
```

Model:

```
def self.to_csv(options = {})
  CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
    csv << column_names
    all.each do |employee|
      csv << employee.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a bit delayed but this is how I fixed same problem.

Change the link to have params.merge to keep the filtered results.

```
<%= link_to "CSV", employees_path(params.merge(format: "csv")) %>
```

I also had to change my format.csv to the following to get it to work:

```
format.csv { send_data @employees.to_csv, filename: "employees.csv" }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In this line you're adding all of the employee models.

```
all.each do |employee|
```

Instead you should have something like

```
def self.to_csv(employees)
  ..
  employees.each do |employee|
  ..
end
```

And call this class method like this:

```
format.csv { render text: Employee.to_csv(@employees) }
```

[(Read more about class methods here)](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/)

Comment: Just tried this and it still downloads all rows instead of just the filtered rows. I can include the new code in the OP if you'd like.